# Can I attach 2 dual-DVI screens to a Radeon 5870?

Tags: screen

The card (ATI Radeon HD 5870 1024 MB) has 1 dual-DVI port and 2 mini display ports.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJF6a.jpg

The dual-DVI is hooked up to a 30" 2560x1600 Dell screen. I also have a 27" 2560x1440 screen. Can I hook this new screen up to one of the display ports? Is there a way to get both screens working?
Both screens are Dual-DVI only - no other hookups.
thanks

Comment: I am seeing that the ports on the 5870 are indeed display ports. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mini_DisplayPort_on_Apple_MacBook.jpg

According to the Wikipedia page, they support up to 2560x1600. That means they might work on my Mac, but I have not seen any definitive confirmation that it will work well.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Store: Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter?fnode=51) or [similar](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=6904&seq=1&format=2).

Comment: Yes that should work. And if not, you might have to connect 1 of the screens via DisplayPort and the other via a DVI-to-USB adapter.